# What is a group $G$ of order $16$ with particular elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have to solve this exercise: Let $G$ a group of order $16$ such that every $g \in G$ is such that $g^2=e$. I have to determine $G$ up to isomorphisms.

We know that $G$ is abelian since $(ab)^2=e$. From the structure theorem, since the partition of $4$ are $\{4,3 1,211,1111\}$, we conclude that up to isomorphisms, $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$, or $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, or $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Is it right?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Is that the correct use of the term idempotent? I thought an idempotent element $g$ would satisfy $g^2=g$

Comment: Yes sorry, the term is incorrect.

Comment: $g^2=e$ (which is not IP, but self inverse. IP would be $g^2=g$) implies that if for some subgroup $S$ we have $g\not\in S$ then $S\cap \langle g\rangle = \{e\}$. This implies that the subgroup induced by $S$ and $g$ can be written as $S\oplus \langle g\rangle$. Thus if $S\neq G$ you can find some $S\subset S'\subseteq G$ with $S'=S\oplus \langle g\rangle$. From this you can step by step show that $G=\langle g_1\rangle \oplus \langle g_2\rangle \oplus \langle g_3\rangle \oplus \langle g_4\rangle$ for distinct $g_i\neq e$. Then note that $\langle g_i\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Thank you, from this the unique possibility is $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 2):

A group where all elements are idempotent is abelian. Therefore according to the theorem of classification of abelian groups, $G$ is isomorphic to a product $$\mathbb Z_{p_1} \oplus  \cdots \oplus \mathbb Z_{p_n}$$ where $p_1, \dots, p_n$ are powers of $2$.

As all elements have order equal to $2$, $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{2} \oplus \mathbb Z_{2} \oplus \mathbb Z_{2} \oplus \mathbb Z_{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

First prove that $G$ must be abelian, then prove that $$(a, g) \mapsto g^a$$ gives an action $\mathbb Z/2 \times G \to G$.  Finally, note that $\mathbb Z/2$ is a field.